# Asperger radius of an integer

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, twin-primes

Say $r$ is an Asperger radius of $n$ if $(n-r,n+r)=(p^{a},q^{b})$ with $p$ and $q$ primes and integral $a$ and $b$ such that $ab=r$. If $r$ is a divisor of a prime number then of course $\min(a,b)=1$.

The famous twin prime conjecture can be reformulated as :
$1$ is an Asperger radius of infinitely many integers.

Are there infinitely many integers admitting at least one Asperger radius?

Comment: " If r is a divisor of a prime number", prime numbers have very few divisors.

Comment: I know. It was a concise way to say "if $r$ is prime or $r=1$". I don't like disjunctions.

Comment: try showing your working

Comment: How many prime powers (with $a,b>1$) have you identified such that $q^b-p^a=2ab$? For $a,b=1$, this simply becomes $q-p=2$, and nothing is gained by restating the twin prime conjecture using the notion of Asperger radius.

Comment: $89-3^{4}=3^{4}-73=2\times 4$., $243-233=3^5-233=2\times 5$, $13-3^2=2\times 2$ are examples.